# Core Data list relationship of Parent Object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

i have two Core-Data entities. One called "Program" and one called "Exercise". Program has a one-to-many relationship to Exercise.

I add Exercises to a Program in another view.
I have one view with all the programs listed and a navigation link which leads to this view.

In this view I want to list all the exercises I assigned earlier to the program. However if I try this code, I get the error message: Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Exercise' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'.

I am new to Core Data Relationships and think I might have forgotten to declare something in the CoreDataClass File. The Problem is that I cant find any other solutions to this question.

```
struct ProgramView: View {

@ObservedObject var ProgramDetail: Program

var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(ProgramDetail.exercise!, id: \.self) { exercise in
                    Text(exercise.name!)
                }
         }
```

This generates the List of all Programs:

```
struct ProgramList: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Program.date, ascending: false)]) var programFetch: FetchedResults<Program>

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(programFetch, id: \.self) { program in 
                        NavigationLink(destination: ProgramView(ProgramDetail: program)) { 
                            Text(program.title!)
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationBarItems(
                    trailing:
                        NavigationLink(destination: CreateProgram()) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle").font(.system(size: 25))
                        })
      }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the Interface?:

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VpnJ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is explaining that you must have a Random Access Collection, so that `ForEach` can iterate through the collection.

For example, Swift's `Array` conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` protocol, so you could use an array.

I'd suggest that you read up on collections, either in the [Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) or on [Apple's Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection).

There are probably a few ways to achieve a solution, but perhaps the easiest method is as follows...

```
struct ProgramView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var programDetail: Program
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Exercise.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Exercise.name, ascending: true)],
    ) var allExercises: FetchedResults<Exercise>
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            // in this line you create an array of fetched results
            // filtered to contain only exercises for programDetail
            let exercisesForProgram = allExercises.filter { $0.program == programDetail }
            
            ForEach(exercisesForProgram) { exercise in
                Text(exercise.name!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes!! This fixed the problem for me. Now to test whether it will save changes back to the Core Data object...

Comment: @FontFamily It saved the changes for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't changed the Arrangement of your To Many relationship to Ordered, `ProgramDetail.exercise` is an `NSSet?`.

You could define a computed property to transform it to an Array of `Exercise`:

```
extension Program {
    var exerciseArray: [Exercise] {
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        return exercise?.sortedArray(using: [sortDescriptor]) as? [Exercise] ?? [Exercise]()
    }
}
```

In `ProgramView` now you could then create your List using the Array as follows:

```
List {
    ForEach(programDetail.exerciseArray, id: \.self) { exercise in
        Text("\(exercise.name ?? "")")
    }
}
```

In case exercise is an Ordered relationship, then `ProgramDetail.exercise` will be an `NSOrderedSet?`.

In this case the definition of exerciseArray is even simpler:

```
var exerciseArray: [Exercise] {
    return exercise?.array as? [Exercise] ?? [Exercise]()
}
```